# Update ListItem in List if key already exists (ReactJS, MaterialUI)

Tags: list, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, listitem

First of all want to let you know that I am using `material-ui` with `ReactJS` and `Redux pattern`.

**Problem:**

I am having a set of array which is being populated in a `List` with `ListItem`. But when array is updated the props are changed and `render()` method of `Component` is called and when data starts populating second time, it shows the error the *key already exists*.

**Code:**

```
 render(){
    return <div>
             <List id='requestList'>{this.bindListItems()}</List>
         </div>
    }

  bindListItems() {

        var listview = document.getElementById('requestList');

        var sortedList = this.props.requestList.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a.requestedTime - b.requestedTime);
        });

        return sortedList.map((name, index) => {
            var listItem = <ListItem key={name.requestKey} primaryText={name.description} />;
            return listItem
        });


    }
```

**ERROR Stacktrace**

```
bundle.js:1099 Warning: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `-KnIXRCJbOqY6rykfand`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.
    in div (created by List)
    in List (created by RequestListContainer)
    in div (created by RequestListContainer)
    in div (created by RequestListContainer)
    in RequestListContainer (created by Connect(RequestListContainer))
    in Connect(RequestListContainer) (created by Home)
    in div (created by Home)
    in div (created by Home)
    in Home (created by Connect(Home))
    in Connect(Home) (created by Main)
    in Main (created by Connect(Main))
    in Connect(Main) (created by AppBarExampleIconButton)
    in MuiThemeProvider (created by AppBarExampleIconButton)
    in AppBarExampleIconButton
    in Provider
```

**How to tackle this problem?**

1. Should i remove the previous `ListItem` and add new `ListItem`.

   If Yes then how to identify the ListItem in `List` of `material-ui`.
2. Should i update the existing `ListItem`.

   If Yes then how?

*Actually new to ReactJS.*

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code

Comment: code added @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: Don't see a problem here unless `name.requestKey` is unique. How are you updating a ListItem

Comment: Can you also print the entire error you are getting?

Comment: @AftabKhan error log added

Comment: @Mohom.R if it is working properly on first rendering and throwing the error after update that means, there is some mistake you are doing in that update part, can you show that code?

Comment: Suppose first list is [key:1,key:2,key:3,key:4] these items are populated successfully. But when new item is added in the above array [key:1,key:2,key:3,key:4,key:5]. As with redux arch render method is called and then it gives me the error. I am looking for a way i will listItem only if it is not added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your logic. The problem is in your data. You have specified `name.requestKey` as key in your code. Take a look at the data that is being fed into the component, you have two different objects with the same value on that attribute.

For using the key, you need to specify something that is unique across your data.

Comment: These keys are autogenerated. They can be never equal

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of this? Flatten Children is thrown precisely for that reason. Just print your requestKey and verify